# Display contents of OpenglES buffer

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to display a yuv to rgb converted frame to the default display. Currently i am doing it with the following code where the yuv to rgb conversion is done by an assembly code which loads CPU. I have found some code to do the same with opengles.

```
Yuv420_to_RGB(ui8buf, buffer1, h1, w1);  /* RGB data will be resulted in buffer1 */
window = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);
ANativeWindow_acquire(window);
wid = ANativeWindow_getWidth(window);
hei = ANativeWindow_getHeight(window);
ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(window,w1,h1,1)

if (ANativeWindow_lock(window, &buffer, NULL) == 0)
{
    memcpy(buffer.bits, buffer1, (4* w1*h1));
    ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(window);
}
ANativeWindow_release(window);
```

I have the opengles routine ending with glDrawArrays. How can i display the result of opengles conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of the code you posted does anything with OpenGL-ES. The typical method to implement color space conversion with OpenGL(-ES) is to load the image into a *texture*, load a *fragment shader* performing the color conversion and *draw* a (full viewport) *textured quad* (that's what glDrawArrays will do, if a quad's geometry has been loaded into the vertex arrays before).

Comment: I have got the OpenGLES equivalent of Yuv420_to_RGB function. What i lack is how to display the converted content. i.e displaying the opengles buffer content to surface

Comment: @RagFox: Well, draw a textured quad of the desired size with the texture being the image. That's how to do it.